# How do I pass parameters to spark.sql(""" """)?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I'd like to pass a string to spark.sql

Here is my query

```
mydf = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE TIMESTAMP BETWEEN '2020-04-01' AND '2020-04-08')
```

I'd like to pass a string for the date.

I tried this code

```
val = '2020-04-08'

s"spark.sql("SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE TIMESTAMP  BETWEEN $val  AND '2020-04-08'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with Python string formatting **`{}`** and **`.format(val)`** as `$val` is in scala.

```
val = '2020-04-08'

spark.sql("SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE TIMESTAMP  BETWEEN {}  AND '2020-04-08'".format(val)).show()
```

---

**`Example:`**

**`In Pyspark:`**

```
spark.sql("select * from tmp").show()
#+----+---+
#|name| id|
#+----+---+
#|   a|  1|
#|   b|  2|
#+----+---+

id='1'

spark.sql("select * from tmp where id={}".format(id)).show()
#+----+---+
#|name| id|
#+----+---+
#|   a|  1|
#+----+---+
```

---

**`In Scala:`**

Use `string interpolation` to substitute the values of variable

```
val id=1
spark.sql(s"select * from tmp where id=$id").show()
//+----+---+
//|name| id|
//+----+---+
//|   a|  1|
//+----+---+
```

Comment: Is Spark and Python basically the same thing?

Comment: @Cauder, `pyspark` is python API for spark, `spark-shell` is scala API.

Comment: Can you please show me one from PySpark with multiple variables?

Comment: Can this method also being used with inner queries in subqueries? spark.sql(s"select * from tmp where id in select (select id from tmp2 where country={}".format(country)))? Not sure how the quotation should be with subqueries?

Comment: If id is a string, this can be used for SQL injection.

Comment: To expand on @Chris's comment: BE VERY CAREFUL using this answer. If the value of "id" is taken from user input, even indirectly, you are leaving your database open to being hacked by the crudest, simplest method there is. (Imagine what would happen if the value were "1; drop table tmp;".)

Either generate the value of "id" yourself, check it against a whitelist, or make sure to escape any special characters.

Comment: I stumbled over this thread when having the same question and want to add, that in Spark 3.4.0 an `args` parameter was added. Using this parameter is far more secure than using using pythons string formatting for the reason @Dausuul mentioned.

See: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.SparkSession.sql.html

Answer (score 8):

Parameterized SQL has been introduced in spark 3.4. You can pass args directly to spark.sql. This is a safer way of passing arguments (prevents SQL injection attacks by arbitrarily concatenating string input).

Example -

```
spark.sql(
    "SELECT * FROM range(10) WHERE id > {bound1} AND id < {bound2}", bound1=7, bound2=9

).show()
```

See [Docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.SparkSession.sql.html) for more examples.